# IIS use COM got Class not registered exception

Tags: iis, com, activex, ocx

I used a WinForm for hosting my COM component and launch it in IIS , it worked fine in VS during test , but after I publish to IIS , I got "class not registered" exception and then application pool crashed . 
At first , I thought it related to COM registering ,But I write a test winform application to invoke same COM and it works fine at the same server .

Anyone?

```
class FaceScannerServerHost : Form
{
    public FaceScannerServerHost(Control control, bool hidden = false)
    {
        if (control.IsHandleCreated) throw new InvalidOperationException("control already committed to wrong thread");
        if (hidden) this.Opacity = 0;
        this.Hide();
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;

        using (initDone = new ManualResetEvent(false))
        {
            thread = new Thread((_) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    //COM control
                    AxC_FaceServerSdk axc = (AxC_FaceServerSdk)control;
                    this.Controls.Add(axc);

                    //crashed here
                    Application.Run(this);

                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    TraceLog.Debug("AxServer", exp.Message);
                }
            });
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

            thread.Start();
            initDone.WaitOne();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

options:

> 1. is asp.net registered to your iis?
> 2. check framework in app pool.
> 3. enable directory browsing.
> 4. make sure all dll's included.
> 5. check if 32 or 64 bit server.

Comment: just point 5 .. I think COM is 32 bit , but i don't know how to do with this .